# Make the mean of the data to be zero

Tags: mean, normalization

I need to make the mean of a dataset to be 0. Till now, I have used StandardScaler (Mean of 0 and Variance of 1) and MinMaxScaler.

But for the problem that I am working on, I would just need to make the mean to be 0. This is how the data looks like:

```
  total_gav   rental_cost
   7379.45  0.000000e+00
   1328.98  4.629630e-13
   4533.67  0.000000e+00
   6924.14  5.092593e-12
   2943.20  4.629630e-13
```

Are there any standard libraries that I could use? Does MaxAbsScaler in preprocessing module does normalize the data to 0?

Any leads/suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Here 's a lead https://ivorix.com/time-series-analysis/normalization-to-zero-mean-and-unit-standard-deviation/

Comment: You can just use StandardScaler with with_mean=False [as stated in the docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler.html#sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler).